# BAPI for getting material and order BOM?

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

Is there a BAPI for getting material and order BOM?

Function modules won't help as those can't be called remotely.

Comment: CS_BOM_EXPL_MAT_V2_RFC might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ** module like this

```
DATA: 
  lt_stpo         TYPE TABLE OF stpo_api02,
  lt_stko         TYPE TABLE OF stko_api02,
  lt_dep_data     TYPE TABLE OF csdep_dat,
  lt_dep_descr    TYPE TABLE OF csdep_desc,
  lt_dep_order    TYPE TABLE OF csdep_ord,
  lt_dep_source   TYPE TABLE OF csdep_sorc,
  lt_dep_doc      TYPE TABLE OF csdep_doc,
  lt_doc_link     TYPE TABLE OF csdoc_link,
  lt_dmu_tmx      TYPE TABLE OF csdmu_tmx,
  lt_ltx_line     TYPE TABLE OF csltx_line,
  lt_stpu         TYPE TABLE OF stpu_api01.

CALL FUNCTION 'CSAP_MAT_BOM_READ'
  EXPORTING
    material     = 'P-501'
    plant        = '1000'
    bom_usage    = '1'
  TABLES
    t_stpo       = lt_stpo
    t_stko       = lt_stko
    t_dep_data   = lt_dep_data
    t_dep_descr  = lt_dep_descr
    t_dep_order  = lt_dep_order
    t_dep_source = lt_dep_source
    t_dep_doc    = lt_dep_doc
    t_doc_link   = lt_doc_link
    t_dmu_tmx    = lt_dmu_tmx
    t_ltx_line   = lt_ltx_line
    t_stpu       = lt_stpu
  EXCEPTIONS
    error        = 1
    OTHERS       = 2.
```

It is remote-enabled so can be perfectly called outside